# How to create a length function that measures the length of a string without using the length function

Tags: javascript, geogebra

Error in JavaScript
TypeError: Cannot call property length in object Geogebra. It is not a function, it is "number". (Error in line #4)

```
alert("Método String de Javascript");
var str=prompt("Entre una cadena de caracteres: ","Geogebra");
var n;
n=str.length();
var i;
for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
    alert("char at "+ i+ " index: " + str.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: ther is no parenthesis => `n=str.length;`

Comment: `i<=n` is wrong => `i < n`. the first char is `str.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 4):

- `length` is property of the string. Its not a function. You need to remove `()`.
- Also you should initialize `n` in a single line. `var n = str.length`
- Also `i <= n` should be `i < n`

```js
alert("Método String de Javascript");
var str = prompt("Entre una cadena de caracteres: ","Geogebra");
var n = str.length;
for(var i = 0;i < n;i++){
    alert("char at "+ i + " index: " + str.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//length does not need parentheses.
alert("Método String de Javascript");
var str=prompt("Entre una cadena de caracteres: ","Geogebra");
var n;
n=str.length;  //length does not need parentheses.
var i;
for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
    alert("char at "+ i+ " index: " + str.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to be in " a better code writting "

```js
alert("Método String de Javascript");
let str=prompt("Entre una cadena de caracteres: ","Geogebra");

if (str) {
  for(let i=0, iMax=str.length; i < iMax; i++)
  {
    console.log(`char at ${i} index: ${str.charAt(i)}`);
  }
}
else
{
  alert('prompt canceled');
}
```

Comment: console.log is not define in Geogebra.

Comment: well... I change for alert, but you have to consider the cancel possibility and his consequences in your code